# GitAhead keeps asking for user name and password continuously

Tags: git, passwords, gitahead

GitAhead keeps asking for username and password, continuously, every minute, even if no action is performed. How can I change this behaviour? Can I set the tool to ask for credentials once per commit, or once a day?

Environment:

> GitAhead v2.6.3 - 2020-07-14
>
> Artix Linux rolling 12.2020 (Arch derivative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. The periodic prompt is caused by the option to automatically fetch. You can turn that off at Tools -> Options... -> General -> Automatic Actions -> Fetch every xx minutes. Then it will only prompt when you do something like pull or push.

Comment: Thank you @jason. Just to let you know, I copied and pasted your answer on GitAhead's development site: https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/issues/531

Comment: Is it possible to enter the password only one time and be saved? like does GitKraken